# when form is submitted scroll div to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a form within pop up I am using bootstrap pop up modal as the form is a bit long so once submitted the message is shown at the top of the form and when user submit's the form it stays at the bottom what **I am looking here is when user submits the form it scroll to top so user can see the message though**.

**Is this possible?** as of it is a pop up modal I am using please review my code below and figure if im doing something wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.reg-form').on('submit', function(e) {
        $('#register').on('shown', function() {
            $(this).scrollTop(0);
        });

        $('.load').fadeIn(500);
        var formData = new FormData(this);
    });
});
```

Here is the html for y pop up modal

```
<div id="register" class="modal" role="dialog">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
        <img class="svg" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/modal-close.svg">
    </button>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Register With Us</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        //here is my form
      </div>
     </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: after submit of the form use $(window).scroll(0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll to top of Bootstrap modal popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813966/scroll-to-top-of-bootstrap-modal-popup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it's possible! just put it:

> **`$('#register').animate({'scrollTop':0},800);`**

and I see you have wrong event name there, **`shown`** should be **`shown.bs.modal`** but nevermind that because you just have to change that line with my code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#regsiter").scrollTop(0);
```

Add the above line in submit function. You don't need to put it in on shown function.

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest is**

```
window.scrollBy(-10000, -10000);
```